# Smooth path definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I keep getting confused with the definition of a smooth path. Here is a definition from William T. Shaw's Complex Analysis with Mathematica:

A path $\phi$ is a continuous mapping from a segment of the real axis into the complex numbers; i.e. $\phi:[a,b]\rightarrow C$.

A path $\phi$ is smooth if it is a differentiable path, and furthermore, the derivative map $\phi':[a,b]\rightarrow C$ is continuous.

OK, now here is my path: $\phi:[-2,2]\rightarrow C$ by $\phi(t) = t^2 + i t^3$. Now, I believe it is differentiable:

$$\phi'(t)=2t+i 3t^2$$

And I believe that $\phi'$ is continuous on $[-2,2]$. However, here is the image of the path:

[image]

See the sharp cusp at (0,0)? This is a smooth path?

I am obviously missing a subtle point.

D.

Comment: Note, that is not the graph of the function in the same way that we talk about graphs from ordinary calculus. Think about it - the actual graph would be 3-dimensional. This is just the image of the function, and does not determine the function.

Comment: The curve's "speed" tends to zero as it reaches the cusp, so it is a sufficiently gentle turnaround that it remains continuous (and even continuously differentiable). Your intuition would probably be better captured with the term **regular curve** (where the tangent vector never jerks around suddenly or takes a rest stop).

Comment: In many books, there is an extra condition on smooth curves, namely that $\phi'(t) \neq 0$ everywhere. (This would make your example non-smooth.)

Answer (score 3):

It is smooth by the definition you gave. Smooth path are probably used to make integration along them... cusps are not a problem. The important thing is to find a tangent vector almost everywhere.

Comment: Almost everywhere? The definition requires everywhere.

Comment: In the cusp (as in any point where the derivative is $0$) you don't have a tangent line.

Comment: There is no *tangent line* at $0$, but there is a *tangent vector* (or perhaps velocity vector), namely the zero vector. Integration over a curve involves its tangent vector, not its tangent line.

Answer (score 2):

In short, a smooth curve $\vec{c}: [a,b]\rightarrow C$ must:

1. map distinct points on $(a,b)$ to distinct values
2. have a $\vec{c}'(t)$ that exists, is continuous, and $\neq\vec{0}$ at any point in $(a,b)$

So no, the example you have given is not smooth, because at $(0,0)$, $\vec{c}'(t)=\vec{0}$ so that it can turn around, which violates condition 2.

(I was going to leave this as a comment for posterity's sake, but unfortunately do not have the reputation to :/)